Unable to plot with matplotlib from an emacs sub-process
I found this question which is very similar to the behavior I am experiencing - however I cannot make use of the answers offered, so I am repeating the issue here.
I have installed Emacs 29.3 on my Windows11 OS and Python through an Anaconda installation.
Launching python.exe from a cmd windows shell and inputting:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()

I get the output I would expect, i.e. a plot window.
From within Emacs, I have updated the python-shell-interpreter variable to contain the path to python.exe, so after starting python-mode I can C-c C-p to run an interactive shell.
However, the exact same code leaves the shell hanging indefinitely and no plot window is created.
The interactive mode switch plt.ion() call works flawlessly from a vanilla windows shell, so that one does not need to issue plt.show() after the plot command, but when invoked in the emacs shell, takes away the hanging after a plt.plot() command but still no window is created. The matplotlib.lines2D object is created every time.
